# How to spell correctly, "hand-written" or "handwritten"?

Tags: spelling

In the online dictionary, such as reverso, there are two ways to write this word. From what I understand, "hand-written" is a noun and "handwritten" is a participle.

How to spell correctly, hand-written or handwritten? It's about text.

Comment: This can be answered merely by using a dictionary.

Comment: Nataly, you can look this up in the dictionaries.

Comment: Thank you, @SovereignSun. In the online dictionary, such as reverso, there are two ways to write this word. From what I understand, "hand-written" is a noun and "handwritten" is a participle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple case of compound words becoming one word from two. They start out as two, they become hyphenated then the hyphen drops out.
You can see this with a lot of words, even the word *tomorrow* is in this group.
So basically write it as one word, that's always correct, but unlike with *tomorrow*, using hyphen is not incorrect with *handwritten* just yet.

Answer (score 1):

**Handwritten** and **hand-written** are both *adjectives* which mean ***written using a pen or pencil, instead of being printed or typed***.

The former version (**handwritten**) is the correct spelling but **hand-written** isn't incorrect too *(alternative spelling)*. As a compound word it used to be hyphened but lost that in years. There are other examples of such words: **homegrown** and **handmade** for instance.

The ***noun*** you're referring to is **handwriting**.

There used to be the adjective **handwrit** *(**hand-writ**)* in Middle English that came from Old-English **handgewrit** - from *hand (“hand”)* +‎ *ġewrit (“writing”)* which means ***any non-printed or handwritten text; something written by hand***